# Retrieve number of occurances in sqlite table

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that has 2 fields:

- street name
- city name

The street name can occur multiple times like this:

```
Hauptstraße   |    Frankfurt am Main
Hauptstraße   |    Berlin
Hauptstraße   |    München
Kirchweg      |    Frankfurt am Main
Kirchweg      |    Düsseldorf
Bahnhofstraße |    Köln
Bahnhofstraße |    München
```

I would like to retrieve all street names (only once) and find out how often they occur.

In my example, I would like to receive the following:

Hauptstraße    |    3

Kirchweg       |    2

Bahnhofstraße  |    2

I have tried the following SQLite statement, but it didn't do what I need:

```
"SELECT thename, SUM(thename) AS mysum FROM streets ORDER BY mysum DESC"
```

It returns a single recordset with a weird number.

How could I achieve what I want to do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT thename, COUNT(thename) AS mysum FROM streets GROUP BY thename ORDER BY mysum DESC;
```